# Sql server, FileTable и доступ к файлам

Tags: sql-server, файлы, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток! Как известно, в sql server появилась разновидность таблиц - файловые таблицы, File tables. У меня есть веб-приложение asp.net mvc, использующее бд sql server 2012. В базе хранятся некие текстовые статьи. В статьях используется множество ссылок на изображения, которые хранятся в файловой системе. Проблема в том, что при бэкапе базы и последующем развертывании бэкапа надо еще позаботиться об архивировании и последующем разархивировании всезх изображений (ссылки на которые, как я говорил хранятся в базе). Вот тут и хотелось бы применить эту самую технологию FileTable чтобы сами изображения по-прежнему хранились в файловой системе, но при этом sql server "знал" бы о них через FileTable. В итоге я завел такую таблицу, добавил в нее свои файлы, но теперь не знаю, как к ним обращаться из веб-приложения, чтобы это выглядело так же, как обращение к обычным файлам. Я могу открыть место хранения этих файлов из интерфейса sql server management studio (правый клик на моей файловой таблице, выбираю пункт Explore FileTable Directory), вижу там все свои файлы, но не знаю, как их использовать. Допустим я хочу поместить изображение из этой папки на веб-странице. Что нужно писать в тег img? 
Раньше это было так:

```
<img src='/images/mypicture.png' />
```

сейчас я пробовал вот так:

```
    <img src='\\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyFiles\mypicture.png' />
```

К сожалению это не дало рещзультата.

Хотелось бы, чтобы я по-прежнему мог ссылаться на эти изображения таким же образом (то есть чтобы сами изображения никуда не переехали), но при этом чтоб в моей базе была файловая таблица, которая бы ссылалась на эту папку. Возможно я как-то невнимательно смотрел, но при попытках воспроизвести это у меня ничего не получалось.

Comment: вы вообще читали какие-либо статьи по данному вопросу? суть этих FileTables была вроде в том, чтобы с помощью `select` запроса выводить данные из файла, при этом в самой таблице хранится только ID файла, а сервер сам потом подгружает данные откуда то. Следовательно в вашем случае извлечение изображений должно происходить с помощью скрипта, т.о. атрибут `src` должен иметь ссылку на php код, извлекающий файл из БД и с нужными `header`-заголовками отправлять их клиенту.

Comment: то есть это некая альтернатива бинарным полям, когда таблицы вместо реального бинарного поля хранят ссылки на файлы содержащие данные.

Comment: речь в вопросе не про пхп. но сути дела это не меняет. Еще вариант, что картинка может быть закодирована прямо в значении src c помощью base64.

Comment: @teran это хорошо, только основная проблема - это  большие файлы. Дело в том, что я бы хотел применить этот подход не столько к  изображениям сколько к видео. Хранить большое  видео в базе и тащить его при каждом запросе из базы получается накладно

Comment: Вы создали вопрос про изображения, очевидно, что работа с видео будет отличаться. Генерация картинки через отдельный контроллер-экшен это в целом часто используемый подход (когда например надо разграничить доступ к файлам). Так что для видео создавайте новый вопрос. Но, как по мне, хранить видео в БД ради одних бэкапов, не лучшая идея. По крайней мере не первый взгляд.

Comment: вообще, похоже, я немного не про то подумал. мои комментарии относятся к типу данных filestream. FileTables это штука поинтереснее.

Comment: mssql умеет хостить soap - да, а хостить таблицы/файлы - не слышал.

Comment: _"Раньше это было так ..."_ - так и оставьте. Нужно сделать так, чтобы url `/images/mypicture.png` сопоставлялся с физическим расположением файла. Для этого, например, в IIS настроить виртуальную директорию (сопоставить `/images` с `\\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyFiles`). Или, как вам уже посоветовали, в приложении добавить контроллер, action которого будет отдавать нужный файл.