# Проблема с виртуальным каталогом в IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть веб-приложение asp.net mvc.  Оно использует базу данных sql server, в которой имеется файловая таблица (Filetable), в которой хранятся некие изображения и видео, которые я вывожу на страницах сайта. Я пытаюсь добраться до содержимого этой таблицы через виртуальную директорию, как мне это советовал @i-one в комментариях к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615819/sql-server-filetable-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC). 
Допустим содержимое файловой таблицы хранится по такому пути:

```
\\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyFiles
```

я создаю виртуальную директорию images в IIS для своего сайта, которая ссылается на этот путь. Далее я пишу примерно следующее:

```
<img src='/images/mypicture.png' />
```

К сожалению браузер не может отобразить это изображение и выдаёт 404 ошибку. 
Я подумал, что IIS не хочет или не может отображать содержимое папки из недр sql-server и поэтому ради эксперимента создал ещё одну виртуальную директорию с названием newImages для этого сайта, но она уже ссылается на папку img, лежащую в корне сайта. Пишу такой html-тег

```
    <img src='/newImages/mypicture.png' />
```

Это опять не срабатывает и выдаёт 404. Но если написать без использования виртуального каталога, вот так:

```
<img src='/img/mypicture.png' />
```

то всё работает. Собственно вопрос: как заставить браузер (или IIS) корректно находить и отображать изображения, лежащие в виртуальной директории?

P.S. пробовал разные варианты задавать путь в src. И `images/mypicture.png` и  `/images/mypicture.png` и `~/images/mypicture.png`, ничего не сработало

Comment: Почитайте как работает IIS, как задается в pool  реальный каталог, и как делается maping виртуальных папок.